# HPC doesn't read .mx file

Tags: import, high-performance-clusters, mxnet-format

I am trying to work in an HPC cluster. Mathematica works fine and I can export tables that I need. However, I had one interpolated data saved in as a `mx` file. I tried to import it, but it gives me some error as this:

```
DumpGet::bgmx: File /home/someuser/research/Mathematica/trial/file.mx
 does not appear to be a binary file or is corrupted.
```

This import works totally fine in my PC but the problem is just with the cluster. Would you please help me how to fix the issue?

Comment: mx files are system dependent, they do not often transfer between systems very well, if at all. (There are exceptions, however!)

Comment: Use `Save / Get` instead of `DumpSave / DumpGet`. The former are platform independent.

Comment: alternatively, .wxf format is compact, platform independent and fast (not as fast as mx though).

Comment: @PavelPerikov Thank you wxf worked

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Get didn't work but changing the format to wxf worked though. Thank you